# Como executar comando DOS no JAVA com privilégio de Administrador?

Tags: java, java-ee, java-8

Olá, tenho um programa onde eu preciso a cada execução dele, ir no servidor, pegar data e hora, e alterar no PC local.

estou executando a seguinte linha de comando:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec('DATE '+dataServidor.trim());
```

e o JAVA me retorna a seguinte exception:

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "date":

eu rodei a linha de comando pelo próprio **CMD**, e me retornou o seguinte resultado:

> O cliente não tem o privilégio necessário

Mas quando eu executo a linha de comando no **CMD como ADMINISTRADOR**, ele executa normalmente e altera a data...

Então acredito que preciso executar o **Runtime.getRuntime().exec()** como administrador também, mas não sei como fazer!

Comment: Seria errado poder executar coisas como administrador... seria falha, ja reparou que quando vai instalar um programa que necessita de privilégios ele pede permissão? então... só com permissão mesmo

Comment: [Elevate Java application while running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30082838/elevate-java-application-while-running)

Comment: Basta rodar o processo pai como administrador, que todos os privilégios serão passados automaticamente.Execute o JAR como administrador, que o comando irá funcionar.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode criar um arquivo .bat que receba o valor a ser usado para o comando DATE e depois criar um atalho para o .bat.

Depois você deve configurar o atalho para ser executado com privilégio de administrador (em Propriedades/Avançados/Executar como Administrador).

Depois você usa esse atalho (nomeDoAtalho.lnk):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start \"\" \"atalho.lnk\"" + dataServidor.trim());
```

Assim só a execução do .bat terá os privilégios e você restringe um pouco o risco.